# what is not working in my code in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am studying C++ and my final Exam tomorrow :(

There are Question in "array" I had in homework. when I write my answer
the output is not true ..!

help me please to correct my code :$

Q1:
Write a program that looks for vowels in a given word, the program
counts the occurrence of each vowel in the word. For example, if the
entered word was “expedition” the program outputs: Vowel ‘a’ occurred
0 times Vowel ‘e’ occurred 2 times Vowel ‘I’ occurred 2 times Vowel
‘o’ occurred 1 times Vowel ‘u’ occurred 0 times Vowel ‘y’ occurred 0
times

Your program should include:

- Array of characters to store the word.
- Function vowels that receives an array of characters. The
  function counts and prints the occurrence of each vowel.

**My Answer**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std ;
void vowels(char const arrayv[],int L)
{
    int a=0,e=0,i=0,o=0,u=0,y=0;
    for(int j=0;j<=L;j++)
    {   
        if( arrayv[j]=='a'||'A')
        {a+=1;}
        else if( arrayv[j]=='e'||'E')
        {e+=1;}
        else if( arrayv[j]=='i'||'I')
        {i+=1;}
        else if( arrayv[j]=='o'||'O')
        {o+=1;}
        else if( arrayv[j]=='u'||'U')
        {u+=1;}
        else if( arrayv[j]=='y'||'Y')
        {y+=1;}
        else
            continue;
    }
        cout<<"Vowel \"a\" occurred "<<a<<" times"<<"\nVowel \'e\' occurred "<<e<<" times"<<endl; 
        cout<<"Vowel \'i\' occurred "<<i<<" times"<<"\nVowel \'o\' occurred "<<o<<" times"<<endl;  
        cout<<"Vowel 'u' occurred "<<u<<" times"<<"\nVowel \'y\' occurred "<<y<<" times"<<endl; 
}
int main ()
{
    int L;
    char arraya[100];
    cout<<"Enter the word:"<<endl;
    cin>>arraya;
    string word(arraya);
    L=word.length();
    vowels(arraya,L);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Q2:

Write a program that reads from the user two words (as array of
characters) the program then copies the shortest word into an array
and prints the word to the user along with number of characters in the
word. As an example: Word1: “example” Word2: “tutorial” The program
would output: the shortest word is “tutorial” with 8 characters.

Your
program should include:

- Three character arrays .
- Function readArray which takes an array of characters and asks the user to
  input a word.
- Function findShortest which receives array of the two
  words, compares between them and prints the shortest one along with
  the number of characters.

Hint: Using string built-in functions are allowed.

**My Answer:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int size=100;
int i=0,j=0;
void readArray (char arrayn[],int size)
{
    cout<<"Enter a word : ";
            cin>>arrayn;
}
int findShortest (int& x,int& a,char arrayx[],int sizex,char arraya[],int sizea,char string1[],int size)
{
    string sx(arrayx);
    string sa(arraya);
    x=sx.length();
    a=sa.length();
    if (x==a)
    return -1;
else if (x < a)  
    {
    for( i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
    {
        arrayx[i]=string1[i];
    }
    return 0;}
else
{
    for( j=0 ; j<100 ;i++)
    {   arraya[j]=string1[j];}
return 1;}
}

int main()
{
int a,b;
char string1[size] ;
char string2[size] ;
char string3[size];
 readArray (string1,size);
 readArray (string2,size);
 if (findShortest (a,b,string1,size,string2,size,string3,size)==-1)
 {cout<<"The word is equal with "<<a<<" characters."<<endl;}
 else if (findShortest (a,b,string1,size,string2,size,string3,size)==0)
cout<<"The shortest word is: "<<string3<<" with "<<a<<" characters."<<endl;
 else
 cout<<"The shortest word is: "<<string3<<" with "<<b<<" characters."<<endl;
    return 0 ;
}
```

thank you..

Comment: Do you know what DEBUGGINS Is ? :)
http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/debugging

Comment: What, exactly, is wrong with your code?  How does it behave differently than desired?

Comment: arrayv[j]=='a'||'A' should probably be arrayv[j]=='a'||arrayv[j]=='A'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first question, conditionals like this don't work like you think:

```
if( arrayv[j]=='a'||'A')
```

this could also be written as:

```
if( (arrayv[j]=='a')   ||    'A')
```

And will always be true. If the character in question is `'a'`, it's true. If not, the value `'A'` will always be true, so we match.

You mean to say:

```
if ( arrayv[j]=='a' || arrayv[j]=='A' )
```

In the second question, your string copies are backwards:

```
arrayx[i]=string1[i];
```

should be

```
string1[i] = arrayx[i];
```

... etc.

Comment: Thank you a lot that help me now I fixed my code and the output be true :$ thanks again